# Can C sort at compile time?

Tags: c, sorting, compile-time

Is it possible to sort elements at compile time in C?

Syntax is of secondary importance, I was thinking of a macro like this:

```
SORT(9, -1, 12, 4)   // expands to: -1, 4, 9, 12
SORT(dog, cat, cow)  // expands to: cat, cow, dog
```

but I won't frown at any API as long as it sorts without issuing a single CPU instruction.

The requirements are pretty lax:

- **Pure C, no C++**. Staying within the C standard would be nice but established language extensions are fair game.
- **Compiler is the only tool allowed**. Unix `sort` or home-brewed code generators are not welcome as they complicate the build step.
- **Any element type is fine**. It's OK if it can sort e.g. numbers but not strings.
- **Fixed-length API is fine**. Having to call `SORT_5` to sort 5 elements is OK.

I realize the solution will probably resort to some language voodoo that barely compiles, I just want to know if it's possible.

Comment: I call it a pre-preprocessor. Basically you write a parser that modifies the source code before the compiler is invoked. Either that, or just put stuff in order manually.

Comment: I think you could do it in C++14 using variadic templates. But in plain C, i don't think so.

Comment: You can do this in C having a different macro function to get each of the `n` elements at each of the `i` positions, using the ?: syntax. But I don't think it will evaluate at compile time with strings though. `int` should get evaluated but there is no way to actually force the compiler to without const_expr.

Comment: If [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) can't do it, it probably is unlikely that it can be done.

Comment: `Having to call SORT_5 to sort 5 elements is OK` Then you can write `SORT_5()` manually: you can do it with completely unreadable `? :` chain. (Not exactly preprocessor sorting, but it probably will be evaluated at compile time if arguments are constant.) Or write a program to generate `SORT_2..50()` for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C/GCC - Is it possible to sort arrays using preprocessor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629219/c-gcc-is-it-possible-to-sort-arrays-using-preprocessor)

Comment: @LieRyan Not really a duplicate, because this question doesn't specify element type.

Comment: If you already know the data, the best option is to sort it beforehand as also specified in the related question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a macro approach:

```
#define GET_1_of_3(a, b, c) ((a) < (b) ? ((c) < (a) ? (c) : (a)) : ((c) < (b) ? (c) : (b)))
#define GET_2_of_3(a, b, c) ((c) > (a) && (c) < (b) || (c) < (a) && (c) > (b) ? (c) : ((b) > (a) && (b) < (c) || (b) < (a) && (b) > (c) ? (b) : (a)))
#define GET_3_of_3(a, b, c) ((a) > (b) ? ((c) > (a) ? (c) : (a)) : ((c) > (b) ? (c) : (b)))
#define SORT_3(a, b, c) GET_1_of_3(a, b, c),GET_2_of_3(a, b, c),GET_3_of_3(a, b, c)

void main(){
    int x[3] = { SORT_3(6,2,3) };
    printf("%d, %d, %d", x[0], x[1], x[2]);
}
```

This works for `int` and works in C, but it's not possible for strings without `const_expr` from C++. Obviously, you're in for a lot of macro-writing to support a large number of `SORT_X`.

Comment: Nice, I think one could even automate writing the expression for getting the nth element. And it could work for small strings with multichar literals (and all the portability problems they entail).

Comment: How many times is it acceptable to downvote a horrible, fragile, possibly disasterous  answer?  Consider: int i=0; int y[3] = {6, 2, 3}; int z[3] = { SORT_3(y[i++], y[i++], y[i++]) };. What do you get? At a bare minimum, put parenthesis around the uses of arguments in a macro, parenthesise your logical operators (&& and || properly) and turn -Wall on.

Comment: I added parenthesis around `(a)` etc because this is a required practice for durable macros, although keep in mind this is obviously a toy example for demonstration to begin with. Also, parenthesizing && and || is a waste of time and almost never helps the code be readable. Would you write algebra that read `(3*x) + (4*y)` ?

Answer (score 3):

Let's consider sorting numbers that can only be 0 or 1. For two numbers, `SORT2` in the following code can sort them:

```
#define SORT2(a,b) SORT2_##a##b
#define SORT2_00 0,0
#define SORT2_01 0,1
#define SORT2_10 0,1
#define SORT2_11 1,1
```

This can of course be expanded to larger ranges and more arguments.

Comment: This could work for anything, but you have to do a define for each possible input. You cannot support sorting even 2 generic `int` without having a prohibitively large file. But in certain limited applications like small enums, it could be feasible.

Comment: I know the limitations, but the question says "any element type is fine". And maybe one can "encode" larger numbers to reduce the number of `#define`s required, for example, one could encode `123` as `((1,2),3)`  and use some specially written macros to compare two numbers .

Answer (score 1):

Not really, you cannot sort in C at compile time (at least if you want to sort a sufficiently large number of compile-time constant integers; in that case having a 300 macros or functions named `SORT_1`, `SORT_2`, ... `SORT_300` is not practical, unless you generate these functions or macros, which you do not want to), however....

Pragmatical approach would be to use your own or some other preprocessor (e.g. [gpp](http://en.nothingisreal.com/wiki/GPP)) and have it do the sort. Or simply, have the numbers in some included file and generate that *sorted* file (e.g. with a `make` rule using `awk` & `sort`)

You could also consider linking using [link-time-optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocedural_optimization) to an LTO-compiled [libc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library), using its LTO-optimized `qsort`. This is not usual, AFAIK, and you have no guarantee that the compiler is smart-enough to inline your LTO `qsort` etc... (AFAIK, current C compilers don't do that).

If compiling with a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (4.8, 4.9 or soon 5.0 in march 2015), you could customize it (e.g. with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) or with your own C++ plugin) to define your `__builtin_my_compile_time_sort` (or perhaps some `_Pragma`) to do the job. This is compiler specific (could mean several days of work, unless you know MELT already)

The simplest thing would be to accept slightly complicating the build step. It is not a big deal.