# Sort by address array of constant pointers and later access by enumerated index

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, gnu, memory-address

GNU C. Embedded. Patching an existing binary. Compiled code looks good, but not nice in C as it relies on manual sorting based on what I understand is undefined compiler behaviour. I am new to C but experienced in assembly language.

I have an array of "constant" (more on that later) pointers sorted by address. These pointers are to a variety of types (hence void). This table extends an existing table in the binary. Simplified example:

```
void * const mytable[] = {array1, array2, &int1, &pointer1, &pointer1+1};
```

The final item &pointer1+1 is to give a termination for the table.

The order in which I am typing array1, array2 etc is based on looking at the map file to determine the address order, which doesn't always fit the order of declaration in the header files, but seem to be sorted by file and type, apparently undefined. This adds risk of bugs being introduced and would be more difficult to check as it grows.

Additionally I am then using the same list and prefixing an "i" in an enum:

```
enum {iarray1, iarray2, iint1, ipointer1};
```

so that I can then access pointers in the table using an index. This is because mytable[] is copied to RAM and modified based on memory allocation, but it is not a compiler managed heap.

It all produces nice assembly as I said, but is there a way to avoid the manual sorting by address and the clumsy looking enum? I am using C99, no libraries, no startup code, grafted into an existing OS and binary.

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if I understand... what is *wrong* with this code?

Comment: When the length of the array of pointers is long it is time consuming and error prone to maintain in order, relying on undefined compiler behaviour and compiling it at least twice with manual checks of the output and changing the source to fix addresses out of order. Then copying the list and prefixing with "i" seems clumsy. Overall, less clumsy than assembler, but being new to C I thought I may be missing something obvious.

Comment: You have not presented a clear problem description. If you can edit your post to clarify what you have tried, and how it has failed to meet your expectations, then this post will get a better response. Please read _[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)_, then edit your post.

Comment: Why don't you just sort the `mytable` array programmatically?

Comment: @MichaelWalz I need it to be sorted at compile time, not run time. Unless you are meaning to sort with the preprocessor?

Comment: @ryyker I'm thinking about how I can condense this problem into a complete and verifiable example. Given its other dependencies it will be difficult.

Comment: @JohnBanks OK, that wasn't quite clear in the question. No way to sort with the preprocessor. Basically, you need to compile once, then find out the adresses of the variables in `mytable` by inspecting the mapfile programmatically with a utility program you need to write (don't ask me details about gcc). That utility would generate the initialisation list for `mytable` in the correct order. Then you compile a second time and hopefully the addresses of the variables in `mytable` stay the same. Hope that's clear enough. The utility program can be written in any language.

Comment: So your real question then is _can C perform compile time sorts?_   _[This post discusses that question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29268723/645128)_.  Comment on whether this will help, or not, and if not, why.  BTW, _[this answer from a high rep poster](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29327901/645128)_ seems to suggest that it is not possible, (with some caveats)

Comment: Thanks @MichaelWalz, that is clear and useful as it confirms that two compilations is not an idiotic method. It gives me some other ideas since I generate most of the arrays from scripts anyway and I could allocate their addresses in their initialisation as long as I tied it together with the section start address in the linker script file.

Comment: @ryyker I do think this might help and will investigate, thanks. Thanks for helping to frame the question, I had not appreciated that it could be a general sort rather than something specific to an array of pointers. I think that answers the first part of the question about sorting at compile time - that it is not at easy problem. The second part of the question is using an enum as an index into an array. Again I think with C this is going to require some other utility to write the enum contents.

Comment: @MichaelWalz, suggested a very similar (utility program) approach to the one mentioned in the second link of my previous comment.  Both suggestions point to some work on your part to make it work, but at least it appears doable.

Comment: This information can't be known at compile time unless everything is in a single compilation unit. If the link order changes, your addresses can change in reference to each other. It's quite possible that a new version of the linker will change things. It's also possible that the loader doesn't guarantee that things will be placed in memory in the same order they exist in the executable. If any kind of lazy loading is happening, things might get placed in memory based on the order in which they're accessed at run time. And if there's any kind of virtual memory, all bets are off.

Comment: @Jim Mischel Thankfully the output is a flash image at a fixed address in the microcontroller, but all the other untidiness applies.

Comment: So all of these pointers are really just offsets from that fixed address?

Comment: @Jim Mischel They are absolute addresses. The flash memory starts at 0x80000000. The pointer array (to which I am appending) can be copied and modifed at run time. The enum supplies the index into the pointer array to make the code readable.